# Jquery will not hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a Live Chat box on page load and then when a hyperlink is clicked, display the Chat box after 30 seconds.

Anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
        $(thislive).hide();

        $("#chatBox").click(function () {
            var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
            $(thislive).delay(30000).show(); // Display after 30 seconds
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="liveChat">
    <!-- Start of LiveChat (www.livechatinc.com) code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
        window.__lc.license = 111111;
        (function () {
            var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
            lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
        })();
    </script>
    <!-- End of LiveChat code -->
</div>
```

**cshtml**

```
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <a id="chatBox" href="#panel-column-3" class="panel-column row-collapse-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="bpanel-column-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                    <h3>@Umbraco.Field("contactustab3title")</h3>
                </a>
                <div class="row-collapse collapse" id="panel-column-3">
                    <div class="inner">
                        @Umbraco.Field("contactustab3content")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATE**
The below works. I think the problem is with the chat script itself. It seems even when its inside the div it has a mind of its own.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
    $(thislive).hide();

        $("#chatBox").click(function () {
            var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
            $(thislive).delay(5000).show(0); //5 seconds
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="liveChat">
    <div>
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors on the console in browser?

Comment: try adding  a 0 inside `show` like this `$(thislive).delay(30000).show(0);`

Comment: no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using the setTimeout() method.
My chatBox hyperlink now has an onclick call to a new method called loadChat().
This then calls another method called showChat which then in turn loads the chat box script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadChat() {
        setTimeout(showChat, 5000) // load the chat icon after 5 seconds
    }

    function showChat() {
        window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
        window.__lc.license = 1111111;
        (function () {
            var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
            lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
        })();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set `timeout` here and not `delay`. Like this,

```
 setTimeout(function(){ $(thislive).show(); }, 30000);
```

so replace

```
$(thislive).delay(30000).show();
```

**Final Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
        $(thislive).hide();

        $("#chatBox").click(function () {
            var thislive = document.getElementById('liveChat');
             setTimeout(function(){ $(thislive).show(); }, 30000); // Display after 30 seconds
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but your suggestion didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your existing display after 30 seconds
(`$(thislive).delay(30000).show();`) Code to

```
$(thislive).delay(30000).show(0);
```

It will work

Comment: Thank you but your suggestion didn't fix the issue

Comment: Please explain the difference, why would your code work?

Comment: @Teemu you should pass duration parameter to make it an animation method. otherwise it will load without the animation.

Comment: @MadDev. it worked for me. decrease delay duration and check . and also you can use fadeout() and fadein() jquery animation functions instead of delay().show().

Comment: @MadDev please check this jsfiddle demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/kitcodes/wp7v5nht/3/

Comment: I have added an answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to do: `$(thislive).delay(30000).show(0);`

According to the documentation for [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

> `delay()` can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. This will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue.

When a duration is provided, `.show()` becomes an animation method.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/fghzg4xm/1/)

Comment: Thank you but your suggestion didn't fix the issue

Comment: @MadDev Then you're doing something else wrong. With the information you've provided, this should work. Test the fiddle in the answer.

Comment: @MadDev do you have any content inside the `liveChat` div? It is poosible that it is empty and you're not noticing any change. You can add some dummy text inside the div and check if this is working.

Comment: Yes it works with my current code. See the update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @MadDev I don't know what kind of chat control you're using and this question is about `.show()` method behaving as an animation method. Hence it is out of scope for this question. You can close this and ask a question relating why your chat isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

try using that code:

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
$('#liveChat').hide();
$('#chatBox').click(function(){
$('#liveChat').delay(30000).fadeIn();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you but your suggestion didn't fix the issue

Comment: Just to check,
If you add a "TEST" element to your html and try to show/hide it with the code above, is it work?
That could focus us on the problem...

Comment: Yes it works with my current code. I think the problem is with the chat script itself. It seems even when its inside the div it has a mind of its own

Comment: Try replce "liveChat" with "panel-column-3" in the code above